# How much a point inside an ABC triangle moved from its origin, knowing the offset of the A,B,C

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, triangulation

I'm trying to measure in % how much the X and Y coordinates of a point inside an ABC triangle moved from its original place, knowing how much % has the A,B,C points moved.

Example: Knowing that the following points moved from their original position: A.x 30%, A.y 45%, B.x 10%, B.y 20%, C.x 70%, C.Y 60%, find out how much the coordinates X and Y of a point P inside the A,B,C triangle moved.

How can I calculate the offset of any point inside such a triangle?

Comment: This is not really a c++ question.

Comment: True, my bad, took out the tag. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: what do you mean by % moved? the points can only move in the positive direction with a percentage of their current coordinate?

Comment: How is the point P given?

Comment: @Nimrod Morag : Yea, the point can only move in the positive direction.

Comment: @Henry I'm trying to calculate how much each point inside a triangle has moved ( knowing that P it's inside the triangle ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the [Barycentric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) coordinates here. Eventually those give you a chance to represent a given point `P` in the triangle with vertices `t1, t2, t3` as `P = a * t1 + b * t2 + c * t3`. Given this, the new coordinates after translating the triangle into `t1', t2', t3'` will result into `P' = a * t1' + b * t2' + c * t3'` i.e. you would just apply the same weights to every corner.

Taken into account you start with cartesian coordinates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates) are the formulas to do the conversion from cartesian to barycentric i.e. find the `a, b, c` I mentioned before.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, mate!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did have the c++, I'll answer the question from a programmer prospective rather than a mathematician so this may not be the best mathematical way to do it. the way i would calculate this is I would first work out the left-most and right-most point of the triangle so this would be the points with the lowest x value and the highest x value then using the following formula we calculate it's percentile position within the triangle.

```
percentile.x = (rightMostPoint.x - leftMostPoint.x) / (point.x - leftMostPoint.x);
```

The Y axis is pretty much the same. Please note as well that firstly this function returns a float percentile so 0.5 = 50% and also a values between 0% and 100% don't guarantee that the point is within the triangle.

Now you know the percentile position you can simply calculate the difference in between the before and after percentile position. i.e.

```
percentileChangeOnX = abs(precentPosBefore.x - precentPosAfter.x);
```